# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on my site with chrome v.57 only

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Site https://sorada.gov.ua has WoSign Certificate. 
Got "A" on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sorada.gov.ua
But when google chrome updated to v.57 we got NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error. All other browsers are OK. 
Does anybody meet same problems?

Answer (score 3):

Given the behavior of WoSign certificates issued after 10/26/2016 where distrusted since Chrome 56. And it was announced that in further releases this CA would be distrusted fully. To cite from [Distrusting WoSign and StartCom Certificates](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html):

> Beginning with Chrome 56, certificates issued by WoSign and StartCom after October 21, 2016 00:00:00 UTC will not be trusted. ... In subsequent Chrome releases, these exceptions will be reduced and ultimately removed, culminating in the full distrust of these CAs.

According to https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13866234 Google now distrusted this CA more than in the last release. To cite from the commit mentioned in the post:

> Restrict the set of domains for which WoSign/StartCom certificates
>       are trusted to the set of domains intersecting the Alexa Top 1M
>       whose certificates are unexpired and unrevoked.

The problem you see is a result of this change.
For a discussion of the problem see [Chromium issue 685826](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685826).

Comment: Now I see. Thank you!